# Best practice for combining a Java Applet/ Android interface?

Tags: java, design-patterns, android

I'm working on an online game, which I am seriously considering writing a Java Applet for it. The game is not overly complex on the features. I'm considering at some point having at least 3 versions of the game, which include a Java stand alone, applet, and Android game. I know from Design Patterns that the best way to use differing things like buttons and the like is to use a Bridge interface, where I have a common template for the common buttons.

However, I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding what to do about the following. I know that Android programs use an Activity structure, which I am well familiar with, and that Applets extend the Applet interface, which I am not as familiar with. I also know that a stand alone java program uses basically a main() function, which doesn't have much structure. I'm convinced that there should be a way to design a common design pattern between the two, but somehow I'm missing what that is exactly. What can I do to make the different frameworks work with as much common code as possible?

Comment: Have a look at libgdx. It's a framework which lets you deploy your game to Android, Desktop and to a browser using WebGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answers to [stackoverflow: recommended-ways-to-produce-app-portable-between-android-and-other-platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977147/recommended-ways-to-produce-app-portable-between-android-and-other-platforms) the best way is

```
 keeping UI and biz logic / model separate
```

and writing seperate gui-s for android, applet, j2se, j2me.

But eaven keeping biz logic seperate is difficuilt because in the android world many api-s are based on the android `Context` which is the gateway to the operating system.

i have developped crossplatform biz logic for j2se and j2me for 2 projects. but i failed to do crossplatform for j2se/android because database and android-Context-api-s where to different from j2se.